# Insert file content (with white line and special characters ) in bash variable for insert in oracle table with sqlplus

Tags: variables, sqlplus, ksh

I write this simpe test.ksh scipt:

```sh
#!/bin/ksh

TEST=$(cat $1 )
sqlplus -S *****/*****@*****<<- EOF
```

```sql
set define off;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
INSERT INTO DBADOC.TEST
(
        "TEST"
)
 VALUES
(
      q'[ $TEST ]'
)
;
commit;
EOF

exit
```

---

Now if i run it with a simple file (3 lines without special char):

```
./test.ksh /home/oracle/scripts/test.txt
1 row created.


Commit complete.
```

**It runs perfectly.**

If I choose a complex file (with blank lines and special character ), it doesn't work:

```
./test.ksh /home/oracle/scripts/check_free_space_dg.ksh
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# ========..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# @(#) NOM..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# @(#) GRU..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "# @(#) DES..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
[...]
```

Comment: I don't use comment in sqlplus in my test.ksh script. The commented rows are in the file that i want upload in the database

Comment: Give an example for a complex file.

Comment: it's a very long bash script file. with blank lines, comment (#) and special character ( ' " ! @ ... )

Answer (score 0):

Change the command in `TEST=$(cat $1 )`, test what works best.

```
# Use filename in double quotes, it might have a space or wildcard
# Skip lines with comment
TEST=$(grep -v "#" "$1" )
# Remove part starting with a hash
TEST=$(sed 's/#.*//' "$1" )
# Remove part starting with a hash and remove blank lines
TEST=$(sed 's/#.*//' "$1" | grep . )
```

Comment: but i want not change the content of the file. I want upload the complete source file (with comment # and blank lines)

Comment: You don't change the file. The variable `TEST` is filtered so you will only use the part of the file in `sqlplus` that you need. An alternative would be changing `q'[ $TEST ]'` into `q '[ $(grep -v "#" "$1" ) ]'`, that might feel different for you.

Comment: thank you. I know that I don't change the source file but the uploaded text is differnt from the real scipt in this way. the upload string must be equal to the script source.

Comment: When you don't want to change the text that is causing the problems, and you don't want to change the way the text is being processed, I can't see how to stop the problems. Good luck!